# Combine one set of time series data with another when some dates are missing in one data set

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, sql

I have a LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet which contains two sets of time series data e.g.

```
|Date-A    |A  | | | |Date-B    |B  |
|2020-01-01|101| | | |2020-01-01|201|
|2020-01-02|102| | | |2020-01-02|202|
|2020-01-03|103| | | |2020-01-03|203|
|2020-01-04|104| | | |2020-01-04|204|
|2020-01-05|105| | | |2020-01-05|205|
|2020-01-06|106| | | |2020-01-08|206|
|2020-01-07|107| | | |2020-01-09|207|
|2020-01-08|108| | | |2020-01-10|208|
|2020-01-09|109| | | |2020-01-11|209|
```

Notice that some dates are missing for (e.g. 2021-01-06 and 2021-01-07 for Date-B)

I want to unify these sets of data using only rows for which both Date-A and Date-B are present. In this case the result would be

```
|Date      |A  |B  |
|2020-01-01|101|201|
|2020-01-02|102|202|
|2020-01-03|103|203|
|2020-01-04|104|204|
|2020-01-05|105|205|
|2020-01-08|108|206|
|2020-01-09|109|207|
```

Observe that 2020-01-06 and 2021-01-07 are omitted, and the correct A and B values are present for all dates which exist in both data sets.

Can I do this in LibreOffice?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new LibreOffice Base database (embedded hsqldb);
2. Create two tables (A, B) that have the same structure as your data columns;
3. In your spreadsheet, select and copy data columns `Date-A` and `A`;
4. Paste those two columns in Base into `Table A` (in table view, select table `A` and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 for columns of `B data` (Date and Data);
6. Create a new Query in SQL mode:

```sql
SELECT "Date-A" AS "Date", "A", "B" FROM "A" JOIN "B" ON "A"."Date-A" = "B"."Date-B";
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Additional Remarks: Don't try to create a new db based on your spreadsheet directly. Those databases don't support JOINs (AFAIK), you will receive strange error messages if you try... (as i did first)